# Assembly problem

Tags: c#

Hi i have a problem with assembly.

I have a program, who create a some class. Into that class i use some other classes from my difrent DLL. In that DLL class method i must use Assembly class, but i will have reference to the program Assembly, and i don't know how to do it.

If (in dll) i user Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), or CallingAssembly i always get the DLL Assembly :/

The GetEntryAssembly always do StackOverFlow exception.

In DLL i can't have any connection with the program.

**EDIT :**

**DLL**

```
  public sealed class MapperSet<T> : MapperSetBase<T>, IMapperSet<T>
  {
    public MapperSet()
    {
      _Mapper = GetSpecificMapper();

      //if (_mapper == null)
      //  throw new NullReferenceException();
    }
    // some methods, not use yet
  }

 public abstract class MapperSetBase<T> : IQuerySet
 {
      protected virtual IMapper GetSpecificMapper()
    {
      Type[] assemblyTypes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes();
      IMapper mapper = null;

      foreach (Type type in assemblyTypes)
      {
        if (type.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i == typeof(IMapper)))
        {
          FieldInfo[] fields = type.GetFields();

          foreach (FieldInfo field in fields)
          {
            if (field.FieldType.GetGenericArguments().Count() > 0)
            {
              Type mapperFieldType = field.FieldType.GetGenericArguments()[0];

              if (mapperFieldType == typeof(T))
              {
                mapper = (IMapper)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
 }
```

**program code**

```
  public class DB : IMapper
  {
    public string ConnectionString
    {
      get { return "TestConnectionString"; }
    }

    public DBTypes DbType
    {
      get { return DBTypes.MsSql; }
    }

    public MapperSet<Person> Persons = new MapperSet<Person>();
    public List<int> l1 = new List<int>();
  }
```

In the MapperSet has some methods. When i invoke one of that i must have a ConnectionString and DbType from IMapper class.

Comment: Are you 100% sure it's calling the `GetEntryAssembly` that is generating the stack overflow exception? Can you show the code you call it from?

Comment: Removed the [assembly] tag; it is used for assembly-language questions.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you could have your main assembly pass the correct Assembly to the referenced dll, but GetEntryAssembly() should also work.

I guess Lasee is right, there has to be some other problem with your code. Show us the code and the stacktrace.

**EDIT:**

In DLL you instantiate types from "Entry" assembly. One of them is your DB class, which has MapperSet constructed during parameter initialization. This in turn calls your MapperSet() constructor, and this causes your DLL to load the "Entry" assembly and instantiate it's types recursively forever, therefore you get stack overflow exception..

How about seting a mapper in a constructor:

```
public class DB : IMapper
{
     public MapperSet<Person> Persons = null;
     public DB()
     {
         Persons = new MapperSet<Person>(this);
     }       
     (...)
}
```

DLL:

```
public sealed class MapperSet<T> : MapperSetBase<T>, IMapperSet<T>
{
    public MapperSet(IMapper mapper)
    {
        _Mapper = mapper;
    }
}
```

You might also want to consider using Dependency Injection.

Answer (score -1):

how about adding a reference from the satellite assembly to the main assembly, then you can use the types directly

Comment: -1: You mean he would need a reference from his main program assembly, to the other assembly, and from the other assembly back to the main assembly? Sorry, not possible.

Comment: no, if M would be your main assembly, and S your satellite assembly, you can add a reference from S to M, and load S dynamically in M. then its possible to enumerate all types providing a specific interface, create objects and so on. S would have access to all types in M.